# Is the Qt Network Authentication module LGPL?

Tags: gpl, lgpl

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/licenses-used-in-qt.html) is unclear whether the [QT Network Authentication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetworkauth-index.html) module is licensed under LGPL or GPL. Has it changed recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Qt is licensed under LGPL 3, except for [some modules specifically noted to be licensed under GPL 3](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html#gpl-licensed-addons) - Qt Charts, Qt Data Visualization and Qt Virtual Keyboard. Since Qt Network Authentication isn't specifically noted as being licensed under GPL, the general declaration that it's available under LGPL applies.