# Is the Qt Network Authentication module still LGPL?

Tags: gpl, lgpl

I saw [this](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/7002/13926) question asking if [QT Network Authentication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetworkauth-index.html) module is licensed under LGPL or not. The answer states that since this module is not specified under [Add-ons available under Commercial Licenses, or GNU General Public License v3](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmodules.html#gpl-licensed-addons), it is LGPL. Checking the link, we can see that, now, this module is specified there, which means it's not LGPL. If we check the documentation of this module, we can see that:

> To link against the Qt Network Authorization module, add this line to
>   the project file:
>
> ```
> QT += network networkauth
> ```

My question: Are `network` and `networkauth` both not-LGPL now? Or is it just about `networkauth`? In other words, can I use functions in [`QPasswordDigestor`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpassworddigestor.html) namespace without making my sourcecode available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of each Qt component mentions the licenses under which it is available.

For Qt Network it mentions

> Qt Network is available under commercial licenses from The Qt Company. In addition, it is available under the GNU Lesser General Public License, version 3, or the GNU General Public License, version 2. See Qt Licensing for further details.

And for Qt Network Authorization

> Qt Network Authorization is available under commercial licenses from The Qt Company. In addition, it is available under the GNU General Public License, version 3. See Qt Licensing for further details.

As you can see, the Qt Network Authorization module does not mention the LGPL license, so it is not available under that license. If you want to use OAuth authentication in your Qt application without having to disclose your source code, then you must go for a commercial license.

However, `QPasswordDigestor` only requires the use of the Qt Network module, which *is* available under the LGPL.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for.